# Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application. Facebook SDK 4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-permissions

Here is the case :

If I previously granted read permissions to my application via

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
```

Then, when I need to share I request publish permissions via :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

Everything works fine until I removed permissions for my application in Web.

If Application was killed or stopped and I need to share I will check if I still have the permissions:

```
if(userAuthorizedMyApp()){
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
} else {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
}
```

Method userAuthorizedMyApp() returns false (accessToken null):

```
private boolean userAuthorizedMyApp() {
    boolean authorized;
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if(DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "accessToken [" + accessToken +"]");

    if(accessToken != null){
        Set<String> currentPermissions = accessToken.getPermissions();
        authorized = currentPermissions.contains("public_profile");
    } else {
        authorized = false;
    }
    if(DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "userAuthorizedMyApp[" + authorized +"]");

    return authorized;
}
```

And I try to do usual login, as if it were first time :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
```

And I receive :

```
public void onError(FacebookException error)
```

> onError, error {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: 190, errorType: null, errorMessage: Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application 123456789123456.}

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: When you get this error, can you try clearing the access token LoginManager.logout(), and redo the log in?

Comment: Actually, by performing the same action for the second time everything works fine - Login screen is openned. But getting error with first attemp is confusing to the user.

Comment: Remember that the access token is cached on the client, so unless you actually make a request, there's no way to validate whether it's still valid. What happens here is that in the failure case, you're calling loginWithPublishPermissions (essentially a request for additional perms, when you already have a token), this fails because the user has removed the app. The second time (success case), you're calling loginWithRead, and this is treated as an entirely new request for auth, which succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()` worked for me. I get the error in the implementation of `FacebookCallback.onError()`, where I call 
`AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync()` which clears the access token in Facebook SDK.

Because this is an async call, I cannot call `loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()` immediately; There is no callback, so I display an `AlertDialog` to the user and when the user clicks "OK", at that time I call `loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()`.

So user experience is not too bad, and it is acceptable for an edge case.

Answer (score 3):

Just do something like:

```
@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {
    Timber.e(error, "Error during facebook login");
    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email"))
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply: I want to customize this message. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7xjlHVL47MbWVVKY1JSbWJGdk0

Comment: You cannot customize that message

Comment: So, We cannot hide it and use other message instead?

Comment: You can - switching app from development mode, into production.

Answer (score 0):

To do a correct validation check the accesstoken if it is null or expired:

```
  AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
  boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
     
  if (isLoggedIn) { 
      //Post Facebook.
  } else {
      manager.logIn(shareAct, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
  }
```