# i got a error in facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook

I got a error while i login through facebook , i don't do any changes in my app, its stop working automatically.

This is my error log please check out.

```
Key error_code expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
01-13 11:10:55.006 17557-17557/fourever.textile W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                                              at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1061)
                                                              at com.facebook.login.KatanaProxyLoginMethodHandler.handleResultCancel(KatanaProxyLoginMethodHandler.java:125)
                                                              at com.facebook.login.KatanaProxyLoginMethodHandler.onActivityResult(KatanaProxyLoginMethodHandler.java:77)
                                                              at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.onActivityResult(LoginClient.java:150)
                                                              at com.facebook.login.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:162)
                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5372)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my main activity code.I am using simple button for facebook login instand of facebook login button.

MainActicity :-

```
private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(com.facebook.Profile oldProfile, com.facebook.Profile currentProfile) {

            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                        com.facebook.Profile profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                        if (profile == null) {
                            Log.e("Profile", "null");
                        }else{
                           // Toast.makeText(Login.this, profile.getProfilePictureUri(20,20).getLastPathSegment() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                                        try {


                                            new SaveServiceSync().execute(object.getString("id").toString(), object.getString("name").toString(), object.getString("email").toString() , regid);
                                            //Toast.makeText(Login.this, object.getString("name").toString() + " Id - " + object.getString("id").toString() + " Email : - " + object.getString("email").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LogoutActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();*/

                                    }
                                });

                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } );


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        salert = new ShowAlertDialog();
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
       // btnFacebookLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookLogin);

        txtsignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsignup);

        Loginprefs = getSharedPreferences("logindetail", 0);
        if (Loginprefs != null) {
            userid = Loginprefs.getString("user_id", null);
            if (userid == null) {
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            getRegId();
        }

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookLogin);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    postStatusUpdateButton.setText("Facebook");
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Login.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_photos"));
                    return; // already logged out
                }else{
                    postStatusUpdateButton.setText("Logout");
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        username.setError("Please enter username.");
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        password.setError("Please enter Password.");
                    }

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username.getText().toString().trim()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        new ServiceSync().execute(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), regid);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        txtsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: What you are try to say.?

Comment: Its quite too simple. Your error log clearly says what is the error. Atleast you should try with your self !

Comment: But same code work perfectly without any changes.I am not do any changes.

Comment: Then why u have posted if working fine

Comment: now it's not working

Comment: Show error line where it is showing error?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: and i think its facebook sdk error

Comment: Anyone have  solution.?

Comment: It gives the line# where the error occurred -- show us which line of your code that is.

Comment: I have the same issue, and the same stack trace, my code is working correctly on many devices but not working on my friend device that give the same problem, this is internal exception.

Comment: in my case the problem has gone when 1) I build a new version with com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+ without determine specific version 2) remove the facebook app!. I think there is a strange conflict between them.

Comment: Ya i try that but i want perfect solution for that.

Comment: If you find please post here on ans.

Comment: Have you Solved the error ?    Same error coming for me.It was working fine before but now it is not working...

Answer (score 2):

This is a low version sdk bug, the real reason will displyed at **web login page**.

So just uninstall Facebook App on your test device, then run your app and call login method, input you account and password, you will see error msg.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution, it works for my problem.

We should sign the apk with the release key, not a debug key, or we should add the debug key hash for the Android-Facebook app, this has solved my problem.

### EDIT:

Unfortunately the problem still appear for the following scenario:

1) After user installed the app and signed up using Facebook account.

2) Then he removed this app from Facebook apps from setting.

3) And finally he logged out, then tried to logged in this problem will appear again.

the solution for me is:
[Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application. Facebook SDK 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822082/error-validating-access-token-the-user-has-not-authorized-application-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `app_id` is incorrect.

If you go to your dashboard on developer.facebook, you will see a App ID, this app id should be added like this in your `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">28759527865892</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb28759527865892</string>
```

and in your `Manifest.xml` you should add the following:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```